# C++ multithreading closes TCP connection

Tags: c++, multithreading

I work on a C++ server where I wait for an network connection. If I  get one I put the socket into a new thread and listen for further inputs. But the problem is that as soon as I have the socket in a new thread the TCP connection is disconnected. I'm using the SFML library.

Here's some code:

main.cpp:

```
int main() {


   std::list<std::thread> user_connections;

   sf::TcpListener listener;
   listener.listen(PORT);

   while (true)
   {

        sf::TcpSocket client;
        listener.accept(client);

        Protocol user_connection;
        std::thread new_con (&Protocol::connect, &user_connection, std::ref(client));
        new_con.detach();
        user_connections.push_back(std::move(new_con));   // user_connections is a list
    }
```

protocol.cpp:

```
class Protocol {
    public:
        void connect(sf::TcpSocket& client)
        {
                std::cout << "Address: " << client.getRemoteAddress() << ":" << client.getRemotePort() << std::endl;
        }
}
```

This prints out:

```
Address: 0.0.0.0:0
```

And if I try to send any kind of message I get the status `4` which is according to [the documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Socket.php#a51bf0fd51057b98a10fbb866246176dc) `disconnected`.

EDIT:

According to @Ted Lyngmo it's because I need to put `client` in a list, because otherwise it runs out of scope. Now if I try to put it in a list via:

```
std::list<sf::TcpSocket> clients;  // executed before while loop
// [...]
clients.push_back(client);         // in the while loop
```

I get the error: ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RNzAjb2C)).

Comment: Too little code to say for sure, but does `client` go out of scope after you've started the new thread?

Comment: Or `user_connection`, for that matter.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I detach the thread and then add it to a list. Should I keep client too?

Comment: @burn_stick It depends on what you mean by "keep". If `client` goes out of scope it will be destroyed and the reference in the thread will be dangling. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I add the thread to a list. I added a bit of code, is that enough or do you need the entire main function?

Comment: @burn_stick "_entire main_" sounds long :-) Can you make it short? If `client` is an automatic variable and the scope ends where you've made that comment, it'll be destroyed - and I'm guessing that would close the connection.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oke i tried to make it as short as possible. I hope it's not too long

Comment: No, that's fine and it shows what I suspected. `client` will be destroyed and the reference you have in the started thread will be dangling. I must run so I can't write a proper answer, you could perhaps `std::move(client)` and receive the client by value in the thread instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't do it with std::move() due to static assertion. I will try to save client in a list.

Comment: Sounds like a plan!

Comment: @burn_stick If you get it working, please do share your solution as an answer. Someone may find it helpful.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i didn't fix the issue yet. I will write an answer as soon as i have fixed it.

Comment: @burn_stick Great, I added one idea as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something built on your current threaded code. It may be a good idea to use a single threaded design and use the [`sf::SocketSelector`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1SocketSelector.php) to wait for events on the listener and all the connected clients instead.

In this *lazy* solution disconnected clients will not be removed from the servers list of clients until a new client is connected.

I've tried to explain it with comments in the code which is an *echoing* kind of server, so you can `telnet` to it, send messages and get them back.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <thread>

constexpr uint16_t PORT = 2048; // what you have in your code.

// A simple struct to keep a client and thread
struct client_thread {
    sf::TcpSocket client{};
    std::thread thread{};
    // The main thread can check "done" to remove this client_thread from its list:
    std::atomic<bool> done{false};

    ~client_thread() {
        // instead of detaching, join()
        if(thread.joinable()) thread.join();
    }
};

// the connect function gets a reference to a client_thread instead
void connect(client_thread& clith) {
    constexpr std::size_t BufSize = 1024;

    auto& [client, thread, done] = clith; // for convenience

    std::cout << "thread: Address: " << client.getRemoteAddress() << ":"
              << client.getRemotePort() << std::endl;

    std::string buffer(BufSize, '\0');
    std::size_t received;

    while(client.receive(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), received) == sf::Socket::Done) {
        // remove ASCII control chars (cr and newline etc.)
        while(received && buffer[received - 1] < ' ') --received;

        buffer.resize(received);

        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

        // send something back
        buffer = "You sent >" + buffer + "<\n";
        client.send(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());

        // restore the size
        buffer.resize(BufSize);
    }

    std::cout << "thread: client disconnected\n";
    client.disconnect();

    // set done to true so the main thread can remove the client_thread
    done = true;
}

int main() {
    sf::TcpListener listener;
    // check that listening actually works
    if(listener.listen(PORT) != sf::Socket::Done) return 1;

    // now a list of client_thread instead:
    std::list<client_thread> user_connections;

    while(true) {
        // create a client_thread to use when listening
        auto& clith = user_connections.emplace_back();
        auto& [client, thread, _] = clith; // for convenience

        std::cout << "main: listening ...\n";
        sf::Socket::Status status = listener.accept(client);

        if(status == sf::Socket::Done) {
            std::cout << "main: got connection\n";
            thread = std::thread(connect, std::ref(clith));
        } else {
            std::cout << "main: accept not done\n";
        }

        // remove disconnected clients, pre C++20
        for(auto it = user_connections.begin(); it != user_connections.end();) {
            // check the atomic bool in all threads
            if(it->done) {
                std::cout << "main: removing old connection\n";
                it = user_connections.erase(it);
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
        // remove disconnected clients, >= C++20
        //
        // std::erase_if(user_connections,
        //     [](auto& clith) -> bool { return clith.done; });
    }
}
```

Edit regarding your edited question where you're trying to put the client in a list:

You're trying to copy the `sf::TcpSocket` and it's not copyable. What's worse, it's not even moveable. The reason the code in my answer works is because it avoids both copying and moving by using [`std::list::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) to construct the element in place in the list.

Comment: okay sorry for the late reply but I just came back and retried this. I came to the realization that my code loops around and "nullifies" my `client` object which is also refereed to by my thread. I haven't tested your code but it looks to me that the same thing happens with your `clith` parameter.

Comment: @burn_stick No worries! No, the `client_thread` taken by reference in the `connect` function is stored in the `user_connections` list and will not get destructed until `erase`d from the list (or the list itself is destructed).

Comment: thats not my problem but (in my code) every time i loop around the program executes `sf::TcpSocket client;` but it always allocates this to the same address, meaning that every connection has the same TcpSocket. What I would need is a way to tellthe program to allocate other memory space for `client`.

Comment: The problem in your code is that `client` gets destructed (and the connection gets closed) in every iteration of the loop as I mentioned in the comments to your question. That's what's avoided in my answer since the client is saved in the list. In your code, you use the destructed `client` in the thread (UB).

Comment: yes i thought the same but I printed the addresses of the objects and when I print it I get after creating a new thread first the message from the main function and then from the thread and both return the same address. Is this because of output delay or can i still read the address from an already destructed object?

Comment: @burn_stick Are you talking about the memory address or the IP address? The memory address will very likely be the same if you create/destroy/recreate an object in a loop like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225463/discussion-between-ted-lyngmo-and-burn-stick).

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently  both `sf::TcpSocket client` and `Protocol user_connection` are destroyed. It's no use to only keep the thread alive, your thread only holds references to client and user_connection, but both of them are destroyed soon after your thread is created (and maybe not even started running).

I read a little bit on the SMFL library and unfortunately, at least the client, which is an object of TCPSocket, is not copyable, nor movable. The SMFL library must be a very old library. Any modern socket library will design socket to be at least movable, meaning that you can move your socket into the thread, or move it to the std::list or std::vector you created.

So, to use SMFL library, which was written without modern C++11 support (the copy & move in C++ was introduced in C++ 2011), together with C++11 library (std::thread), will be quite painful.

You can probably use std::shared_ptr to hold a newly created protocol & client, and pass shared_ptr into thread or into the list you created.

I don't know what Protocol exactly does, a rough pseudo code is as follows,

```
std::shared_ptr<TcpSocket> client = std::make_shared<TcpSocket>();
listener.accept(*client);
std::shared_ptr<Protocol> protocol = std::make_shared<Protocol>();
// copy the pointer into thread, they will be deleted after the thread is done
std::thread new_con ( [client, protocol] () { protocol->connect(*client); } );
```

or, protocol can probably be defined in the thread,

```
std::shared_ptr<TcpSocket> client = std::make_shared<TcpSocket>();
listener.accept(*client);
std::thread new_con ( [client] () { 
    Protocol protocol;
    protocol.connect(*client); 
} );
```

Comment: "_...will be quite painful..._" - Yeah it requires a little more work than what one would expect but packaging both the thread and the socket in a struct and then storing the instances in a list works fine as I showed in my answer.